# how to get the object returned by firebase onValue()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am quite bit new to react native and to front end development in general, so please bear with me.
I am writing a simple react native app that Retrieves data of map markers from firebase and display them on a map. I wrote a python program that adds new markers to firebase regularly, which means that the data stored on the database is not static.
I followed this documentation from google and reading data through an event listener works fine in my app, but I couldn’t store the data of the object inside a variable out of onValue.
My question is how to get the retrieved data from the database, and display it on the map view?

here is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { FlatList, Keyboard, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import styles from './styles';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from 'firebase/database';
import { firebase} from '../../firebase/config'
import { app} from '../../firebase/config'



export default function HomeScreen(props) {

  const db = getDatabase();

  const f1 = ref(db, '/');
  onValue(f1, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
  });

  const uniRegion = {
    latitude: 25.2863943,
    longitude: 55.4749801,          
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView style={styles.map} region={uniRegion}
             showsUserLocation={true} >
    <Marker coordinate={uniRegion} />
    </MapView >
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data in any variable you want, but need to make sure that React re-renders its UI when the data is loaded or updated. To do that, you'll want to use store the data in the state using a `useState` hook.

For some examples of this:

- [How to update Firebase data to the React application in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871401/how-to-update-firebase-data-to-the-react-application-in-realtime/59871491#59871491)
- [How to return a value from Firebase to a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71012463/how-to-return-a-value-from-firebase-to-a-react-component/71012822#71012822)
- [How to properly update state with Firebase and useEffect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708542/how-to-properly-update-state-with-firebase-and-useeffect/58710950#58710950)
- [React + Firebase using hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208207/react-firebase-using-hooks/56213515#56213515)
- [React Native and Firebase Real Time Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283883/react-native-and-firebase-real-time-database)

Comment: thank you for your help, after adding the setCount in side the onValue I am getting the following error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: this is what I did:   
  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);

  onValue(f1, (snapshot) => {
const data  = snapshot.val();
setCount(data);

  }
  );

Comment: That sounds like a new problem. If it persists, I recommend posting a new question, with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read that link; the more closely you follow the guidance, the better the chances that someone can help.